# Format Word File, so the printed file will be Folded and mantain continuiti between pages?

Tags: text, ms-word, formatting, ms-office, inline-editing

I'm working on a Word file, that will be printed. The idea is, this whole document, when printed, should look like an A3 notebook.
The problem that I have, is that I don't know how should I format the style of the pages so I can maintain continuity between them because:
In my head, I formated the file as an A4, landscape, and grouped the text in 2 columns. But when I would fold every page, the second column, which should be my second page, would actually become the last page in my future notebook.

Mentions:

- I can't format it as  A3 pages and ask the printing company to "glue" the pages together because the document will only be around ~20 pages and the "glue" wouldn't stick them together. This is why I need them folded, so I can staple them in the middle of every page.
- I also apologize if my task isn't that clear, I tried to explain the best I could.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers). In any event, Word has this functionality built in. It's called bookfold printing.